# Kibana elasticsearch control list

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I created a control list with two values ​​prod and pprod. the problem when I choose prod it even displays the pprod. how to poster just prod.

Hello .
I created a control list with two values ​​prod and pprod. the problem when I choose prod it even displays the pprod. how to poster just prod.

Comment: Hi Mohamed , can you share more details? Sounds like you are using the wrong field for the control list becase it should filter.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think this . Because the results is good . But when a chose the word “prod” .i found  in the result the “pprod” .
thnks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).